# offline web page browsing

Tags: php, javascript, proxy, offline

I have several clients and one server in my network.
i'd like clients have no direct access to internet. i want that clients send his url request to server via a port ( for example 6098 port or any), then server send those url data (such as html text image etc)  to client in response .

do you have any idea or solution for this case?
can i develop client side program as web-application ? (using javascript,php)
what should i do in server side programm? must i develop a server program? how?
is there any kind of this server now developed?

excuse me for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not develop. Pick a proxy server solution off the self.

Faster, safer, and most probably much more efficient, as the creator surely put a lot of time and people to make the proxy work as smooth, as fast, as secure and as reliably as possible.

Comment: thanks; but can proxy listen to another port instead of 80? so how i should send my request to proxy which listen to port for example 6090?

Comment: Even without knowing any proxy particulary, I say 'yes, absolutely'. Any respectable server will be configurable far beyond your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something called a "web proxy server". There is a list of them in wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: but won't use port 80, can i modify proxy server to listen another port? then how to send request in my web app?